# Format after turning a list of floats into a pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter, series

I have a pandas Series with values such as [10000, 300000, 0, 250000...]. I am trying to normalize these values and has successfully done so by this bit of code

```
def normalize (oldvalue, minvalue, maxvalue):
    newvalue = (oldvalue - minvalue) / (maxvalue - minvalue)
    return newvalue

newvalues = []
for x in df.cost:
    newvalues.append(normalize(int(x), int(df.cost.min()), int(df.cost.max())))
```

So now *newvalues* is a list of the normalized values. I have tried different ways of replacing the original Series values with the new normalized values. I have tried the following:

```
replace = pd.Series(newvalues)

df.cost.replace(df.cost.tolist(), newvalues)
```

I end up with the following format:

```
0      3.061224e-01
1      6.632653e-01
2      0.000000e+00
3      1.632653e-01
4      0.000000e+00
5      6.122449e-01
```

While the values in newvalues looks like this:

```
[0.30612244897959184, 0.6632653061224489, 0.0, 0.16326530612244897, 0.0, 0.6122448979591837]
```

Any help is appriciated

Comment: try pd.options.display.float_format = '${:,.17f}'.format after/before your code

Comment: and pd.reset_option('all') to reset it back to original once you're done with your execution. Note : reset all resets all your display settings, for more info : check https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html

Comment: First, try to use a vectorized approach like this: `(df.cost-df.cost.min())/(df.cost.max()-df.cost.min())` it will be way more efficient, and as pandas will be responsible for formatting, it might solve your issue. If it doesn't, wan you provide us with `df.dtypes`?

Comment: @anky_91 Thank you that worked

Comment: @ysearka Since I have to normalize for every row in the Series, how am I supposed to do that with the vectorized approach?

Comment: @JoachimMorken Have you tried the piece of code I gave? If it doesn't perform what you're looking for, it means that I'm missing something. But IIUC it should.

Comment: @ysearka Tbh I am not sure where to put your code. As I have to calculate the norm for each row in the Series? I already do the same code in the for loop

Comment: @JoachimMorken : if you really think my answer works, kindly [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks.

Comment: @JoachimMorken Indeed, it is a replacement of all the code you've put in your question. It does perform the same computation but faster in inside pandas framework, so that you don't have float types modification while computing.